# Extracting Attributes and Inner Text from XML

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML file that has about 10,000 lines that I would like to extract some data to a CSV file.

What I am having a problem with is extracting the `id` attribute and the inner text of the alliance name tag. If anyone can shed some light as to why the ID doesnt show and how to get the innertext it would be very helpful.

**Repeating Sample Data**

```xml
<players>
<towns>
  <town>
    <player>
      <playername id="1">MyName</playername>
      <playerrace>Human</playerrace>
      <playeralliance>
        <alliancename id="18">DaVS</alliancename>
        <alliancetag>DaVS</alliancetag>
        <alliancetax>0.01</alliancetax>
      </playeralliance>
    </player>
  </town>
  <town>
    <player>
      <playername id="2">Tonka</playername>
      <playerrace>Human</playerrace>
      <playeralliance>
        <alliancename id="18">DaVS</alliancename>
        <alliancetag>DaVS</alliancetag>
        <alliancetax>0.01</alliancetax>
      </playeralliance>
    </player>
  </town>
  <town>
    <player>
      <playername id="2">Tonka</playername>
      <playerrace>Human</playerrace>
      <playeralliance>
        <alliancename id="18">DaVS</alliancename>
        <alliancetag>DaVS</alliancetag>
        <alliancetax>0.01</alliancetax>
      </playeralliance>
    </player>
  </town>
  <town>
    <player>
      <playername id="2">Tonka</playername>
      <playerrace>Human</playerrace>
      <playeralliance>
        <alliancename id="18">DaVS</alliancename>
        <alliancetag>DaVS</alliancetag>
        <alliancetax>0.01</alliancetax>
      </playeralliance>
    </player>
  </town>
  <town>
    <player>
      <playername id="2">Tonka</playername>
      <playerrace>Human</playerrace>
      <playeralliance>
        <alliancename id="18">DaVS</alliancename>
        <alliancetag>DaVS</alliancetag>
        <alliancetax>0.01</alliancetax>
      </playeralliance>
    </player>
  </town>
  <town>
    <player>
      <playername id="2">Tonka</playername>
      <playerrace>Human</playerrace>
      <playeralliance>
        <alliancename id="18">DaVS</alliancename>
        <alliancetag>DaVS</alliancetag>
        <alliancetax>0.01</alliancetax>
      </playeralliance>
    </player>
  </town>
  <town>
    <player>
      <playername id="2">Tonka</playername>
      <playerrace>Human</playerrace>
      <playeralliance>
        <alliancename id="18">DaVS</alliancename>
        <alliancetag>DaVS</alliancetag>
        <alliancetax>0.01</alliancetax>
      </playeralliance>
    </player>
  </town>
  <town>
    <player>
      <playername id="2">Tonka</playername>
      <playerrace>Human</playerrace>
      <playeralliance>
        <alliancename id="18">DaVS</alliancename>
        <alliancetag>DaVS</alliancetag>
        <alliancetax>0.01</alliancetax>
      </playeralliance>
    </player>
  </town>
  <town>
    <player>
      <playername id="2">Tonka</playername>
      <playerrace>Human</playerrace>
      <playeralliance>
        <alliancename id="18">DaVS</alliancename>
        <alliancetag>DaVS</alliancetag>
        <alliancetax>0.01</alliancetax>
      </playeralliance>
    </player>
  </town>
  <town>
    <player>
      <playername id="2">Tonka</playername>
      <playerrace>Human</playerrace>
      <playeralliance>
        <alliancename id="18">DaVS</alliancename>
        <alliancetag>DaVS</alliancetag>
        <alliancetax>0.01</alliancetax>
      </playeralliance>
    </player>
  </town>
  <town>
    <player>
      <playername id="3">Sinner</playername>
      <playerrace>Human</playerrace>
      <playeralliance>
        <alliancename id="1">Harmless?</alliancename>
        <alliancetag>TH</alliancetag>
        <alliancetax>0.00</alliancetax>
      </playeralliance>
    </player>
  </town>
  <town>
    <player>
      <playername id="3">Sinner</playername>
      <playerrace>Human</playerrace>
      <playeralliance>
        <alliancename id="1">Harmless?</alliancename>
        <alliancetag>TH</alliancetag>
        <alliancetax>0.00</alliancetax>
      </playeralliance>
    </player>
  </town>
  <town>
    <player>
      <playername id="3">Sinner</playername>
      <playerrace>Human</playerrace>
      <playeralliance>
        <alliancename id="1">Harmless?</alliancename>
        <alliancetag>TH</alliancetag>
        <alliancetax>0.00</alliancetax>
      </playeralliance>
    </player>
  </town>
  <town>
    <player>
      <playername id="10">Kumomoto</playername>
      <playerrace>Elf</playerrace>
      <playeralliance>
        <alliancename id="1">Harmless?</alliancename>
        <alliancetag>TH</alliancetag>
        <alliancetax>0.00</alliancetax>
      </playeralliance>
    </player>
  </town>
  </towns>
</players>
```

**Current Code**

```psh
$xml.selectNodes('//playeralliance') |
  select alliancename.id, allianceticker, alliancetaxrate
```

**Output**

```
PS C:\Users\jon> $xml.selectNodes('//playeralliance') | select alliancename.id, alliancename, alliancetag, alliancetax

alliancename.id alliancename alliancetag alliancetax
--------------- ------------ ----------- -----------
                alliancename DaVS           0.01           
                alliancename DaVS           0.01           
                alliancename DaVS           0.01           
                alliancename DaVS           0.01           
                alliancename DaVS           0.01           
                alliancename DaVS           0.01           
                alliancename DaVS           0.01           
                alliancename DaVS           0.01           
                alliancename DaVS           0.01           
                alliancename DaVS           0.01           
                alliancename TH             0.00           
                alliancename TH             0.00           
                alliancename TH             0.00           
                alliancename TH             0.00
```

**Past Code Example**

```psh
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'C:\Users\jhold\Desktop\Illyriad Data\sample.xml';

$xml.towns.town.player;

foreach($item in $xml.playeralliance)
{
    $allianceName = $item
    #$allianceID = $item.id
    #$allianceTicker = $item.allianceticker
    #$allianceTax = $item.alliancetax

    Write-host "Name: " $allianceName 
    #Write-host "ID: " $allianceID
    #Write-host "Ticker: " $allianceTicker
    #Write-host "Tax: " $allianceTax
}
```

Comment: it aint even well formed

Comment: Updated the XML Data. I was trying not to post a bunch of the same data.

Comment: starting at 16:00 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8k-oqBlntY

Comment: The video was very informative and I did learn a lot from it. Unfortunately it didnt help me with this exact problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for this:

```
$xml.SelectNodes('//playeralliance') |
  Select-Object @{n='allianceid';e={$_.alliancename.id}},
                @{n='alliancename';e={$_.alliancename.'#text'}},
                @{n='allianceticker';e={$_.alliancetag}},
                @{n='alliancetaxrate';e={$_.alliancetax}}
```

Comment: This is perfect. I was able to get everything I need and it exported to Csv very cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

that's powershell v3+ if I remember correctly

```
PS C:\Users\joshua> [xml]$xml = Get-Content C:\Users\joshua\Desktop\sample.xml

$xml.town.player

$xml.town.player.playername.id

$xml.town.player.playername.'#text'

playername playerrace playeralliance
---------- ---------- --------------
playername Elf        playeralliance
10
MyName



PS C:\Users\joshua>
```

Comment: I dont get any results back using $xml.towns.town.player.playeralliance.'#text'

Comment: you don't have text node there
$xml.town.player.playeralliance.alliancename.'#text'
FoxTwo

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by I dont have a text node there?

Comment: it's at $x.players.towns.town.player.playeralliance.alliancename.'#text'

Answer (score 1):

Make use of expand property... It works for me.

```
$item | select -expandproperty allianceticker
```